# Actionscript Regex to determine full stop

Tags: regex, actionscript-3

Another actionscript problem. I need to extract the first sentence from a block of text but if the first sentence does not contain more than 80 characters then I need to extract the first and second sentence.

The example code below is an attempt to find the sentences and not get confused with the other perios/full stops in the eg text.

I have this test code:

```
import flash.text.TextField;

var descr:String = 
"The temperature was 32.8 degrees Celsius. His B.Sc. degree was deemed insufficient. the Dr. owed B. the bank USD 4000.50 which he had not paid back. On 27.07.2004 a major earthquake occurred. It was 17.05 by the clock.";

var array:Array;

array = descr.split(/\s[a-zA-Z]{3,30}\.\s/);

trace(descr); //put original above output for checking against
trace(array+"\n"+array.length);//ouput
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Will check back when I get up.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using a lazy quantifier of the form `{m,n}?` and a positive lookahead to make sure that the period is one which matches at the end of the sentence:

```
^.{0,79}?(?=\.(?:$| [A-Z]))\..+?(?=\.(?:$| [A-Z]))\.|^.{80,}?(?=\.(?:$| [A-Z]))\.
```

The regex is of two parts:

```
^.{0,79}?(?=\.(?:$| [A-Z]))\..+?(?=\.(?:$| [A-Z]))\.
```

To match the two first sentences if the first sentence is below 80 characters.

```
^.{80,}?(?=\.(?:$| [A-Z]))\.
```

To match the first sentence (when the first part fails, that is when the first sentence is above 80 chars).

`^` matches the beginning of the string.

`.{0,79}?` matches at most 79 characters and will stop at the closest sentence period.

`.{80,}?` matches at least 80 characters and will stop at the closest sentence period.

`.+?` is for the second sentence and can contain any number of characters.

`(?=\.(?:$| [A-Z]))` is a positive lookahead which matches a period that is either at the end of the string (`\.$`) OR, a period followed by a whitespace and a capital letter (`\. [A-Z]`).

Then match the period with `\.`.

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/wH4rQ4)

NOTE: This is a regex to *match* and not split.

Comment: Great! But now I need it to give me 1 sentence if the sentence character length exceeds 80 or ONLY 2 sentences if the first sentence is less than 80 characters.

The regex matches all sentences under 80 characters ATM. Which gives me:

'The temperature was 32.8 degrees Celsius. His B.Sc. degree was deemed insufficient. the Dr. owed B. the bank USD 4000.50 which he had not paid back.'

When I only need 'The temperature was 32.8 degrees Celsius. His B.Sc. degree was deemed insufficient.'

Comment: @user389391 Ooh, I think I misunderstood your question the first time. I updated my answer.

Comment: I tried your new expression but still the same result. Gets all three sentences instead of just the two. Maybe I was not clear enough :-) If the first sentence did not match then I only need it to get the first and second/next sentence which could be of any length. SO if the first sentence is not long enough please get then next sentence as well.

Comment: @user389391 Your sample sentence has an uncapitalised `t` in `The Dr. [...]` (If I capitalise it, [it works](http://regex101.com/r/pN6eA7)). If you have improper sentences, this regex won't work, and you probably cannot do anything about that. Are you trying to put text in a box and make sure it's not longer than the box? You could try using a regex to produce line by line with at most 80 characters if so.

Comment: HI there. The text will be from RS feed descriptions. I only need to take the first sentence or if that is to short then the first + second. The text I supplied is a complex example of the RSS description variability. Capitalization, while needed to be preserved, is not a concern to me.

Comment: @user389391 Okay, but you don't understand that it's practically impossible to determine what delimits a sentence and what doesn't. How would you determine what a sentence is if you don't have something to identify the correct end of a sentence if proper capitalization is not present?

Comment: I accept what you are saying :-) It then all works. Thank you VERY much. I will study this as I am still learning regex